# How to use waitlists with price sets that have registration limits?

Tags: price-sets, civievent, waitlist

I have built an event registration that uses price sets to set limits on the number of people who can register from certain audiences. Once these limits are reached it is currently responding "event is full."

The desired behavior is that either using the price-sets or using participant types, the event would always waitlist when the limits are exceeded, and that the waitlist based on the group, rather than the event as a whole.

Example: 
Group A has a limit of 50 seats
Group B has a limit of 20 seats
Group C has a limit of 100 seats

If Group A gets full, they go on the waitlist. Other groups can continue normal registration until they are full, and then they are waitlisted. Spots that open up for waitlisted registrants must come from the group they selected initially.

Comment: Please provide more detail on the structure of your price sets. Also please provide details of the CiviCRM version and the CMS and version you are using.

Comment: The price set has one field with 3 options. Each option has a registration limit. The site is deployed on Civi 4.5.5 and Joomla 3.4, but any solution would need to be CMS agnostic.

Comment: Question has been edited to add more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see to accomplish this without writing custom code is to create 3 Civi events. You'd then:

- Create a page on your website describing the event, with 3 different registration links.
- Give your 3 events the same date, event type, etc, but different limits and pricing structures.
- All three can be set to roll over to waitlist after the limit is reached.
- Give your events clear names like "Our Gathering (Group A)", "Our Gathering (Group B)" etc.
- Set up an event participant report that lists the participants from all 3.

Comment: I ended up using this approach along with a little Javascript to obscure what is actually happening on the front end. Ultimately I think it would be worth exploring changing the wait list functionality to be attached to the participant types.

Answer (score 1):

The waitlist feature applies to the whole event when "Max Participants" is set on the event info & configuration page, not to limits set for individual options in a price field.

The usual behaviour when an price field option is "fully subscribed" is that the option can no longer be selected during the registration process.

So the behaviour you describe is not usual and the behaviour you want is not 'out-of -the box' CiviCRM.

Someone else will have to advise on how to get the behaviour you want.

But a first step would be to upgrade your site to 4.5.8 which is the latest version in the 4.5 series so that the behaviour when an price field option is "fully subscribed" is operating correctly. It would not be sensible to create custom code on a site with a bug.

Comment: While that may be a bug, fixing that also wouldn't solve my problem. I would either need a fully subscribed option to go to the waitlist, or make it possible to allow registration limits based on participant type. I'm definitely looking for an outside of the box solution that will probably require a PR.